# How to add non-button items to Commandbar?

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-fabric

Can components other than button be added to  [Commandbar](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/commandbar)  ? I want to add a  [SearchBox](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/searchbox) to the  [Commandbar](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/commandbar) . Is that possible?